# Field with 729 elements.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field with 729 elements. How many distinct proper subfields does $\mathbb{F}$ contain. Please be generous and tell the reason also.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you think of *any* subfields?

Comment: What do you know about the structure of finite fields which might helping answering this question?

Comment: You've got some good hints here already. One more hint: $729=3^{6}$.

Comment: ans is 3 right?

Comment: Yes, it is @देवेन्द्रprasad : $\;\Bbb F_3\;,\;\;\Bbb F_{3^2}\;,\;\;\Bbb F_{3^3}\;$

Comment: @Timbuc   thanks to you

Answer (score 6):

Hint: a field $\;\Bbb F_{p^m}\;$ is a subfield of $\;\Bbb F_{p^n}\;$ iff $\;m\mid n\;$ .

Further hint: in order to prove the above , it may be really helpful to consider all those fields as linear spaces over their common prime field $\;\Bbb F_p\;$